# Cannot make \arraybackslash work after defining custom columns

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, width

I use:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{fwLa}[1]{>\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{fwCa}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{fwRa}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

And then:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Measured and Computed Air Properties}\label{airprops}
\begin{tabular}{|c | c c|}
\hline
\textbf{Property} & \textbf{Measured Value} & \textbf{Absolute Uncertainty} \\
\hline
Pressure $\left[\textit{mmHg}\right]$ & 750.142 & $\pm$0.05 \\
Temperature $\left[\textit{$^{\circ}$C}\right]$ & 22.5 & $\pm$0.5 \\
Density $\left[\textit{$\frac{kg}{m^{3}}$}\right]$ & 1.177 & $\pm$0.045 \\
Dynamic viscosity $\left[\textit{$\frac{kg}{ms}$}\right]$ & 1.766$\times10^{-5}$ & $\pm$81.810$\times10^{-6}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I get:

```
Package array Error: Empty preamble: `l' used \maketitle
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr \textbf{Property}...
```

Comment: But the `tabular` you posted does not use customised column types anyway.... The error means that you have tried to put more cells into a row than you have defined columns.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Side note, why ``\let\newline\\`` ???

Comment: unrelated but don't use `[h]` it usually generates a warning that it is being changed to `[ht]` and even then is quite likely to force teh float to the end of the document.

Answer (score 7):

You can not use `fwRa`as an array column, it has to be a single token.

Comment: Then may be `\fwRa`?

Comment: @Manuel actually, it can, but by far the most common usage is a single letter not a command sequence.